# Base Docker in Docker image cannot start Docker daemon

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-in-docker

I have reduced my dockerfile to the following

```
FROM docker:latest
EXPOSE 3000
```

But when running the image, docker daemon cannot start.

Running `dockerd` in the container results in a large chain of info, errors and warnings ending with the following:

```
WARN[2021-12-09T01:07:36.691842800Z] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout". Reconnecting...  module=grpc
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: Iptables not found
```

Am I missing something? I can manually install iptables but then it fails again with

```
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
```

So I am assuming I have some setting wrong as it seems to be working out of the box here https://hub.docker.com/_/docker

I am running docker on Windows with the WSL 2 backend.

Comment: The `docker:dind` image is different from `docker:latest`, and it does [a lot of extra setup](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/8baa881aab85f8398d2edbbcc0da4bd1f556dd98/20.10/dind/Dockerfile).  Do you actually need to run a nested Docker daemon?

Comment: Yes, I need to run a docker build in generated code for linux as part of a FastAPI client generation.

Comment: Can you use the host's Docker daemon instead; `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ... your-image`?  DinD is pretty complex.  If you really needed it consider running it as a separate container next to your application container.